# Numpy Vectorize Behavior

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to np.vectorize a a single period saw tooth function using numpy.vectorize with this lambda function:

```
saw = lambda x: 0 if x < -2 or x > 2 else x
```

But when I apply the vectorized `saw` to this array:

```
array([-4.    , -3.57894737, -3.15789474, -2.73684211, -2.31578947,
   -1.89473684, -1.47368421, -1.05263158, -0.63157895, -0.21052632,
    0.21052632,  0.63157895,  1.05263158,  1.47368421,  1.89473684,
    2.31578947,  2.73684211,  3.15789474,  3.57894737,  4.        ])
```

I get:

```
array([ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1, -1, -1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0,
    0,  0,  0])
```

Whats going on here?

For consideration I am using Python 2.7 with numpy 1.10.2

Comment: Please show all relevant code you used to generate this.  It looks like somehow your data is being converted to integers. Maybe change to `saw = lambda x: 0.0 if x < -2 or x > 2 else x`?

Comment: Note: It'd be better to use `np.where` for this instead of `np.vectorize`. `np.vectorize` is really slow.

Comment: In this case, `where` is 2x faster than `vectorize`. With boolean masking I can make it 3x.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [`np.vectorize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) documentation:

> The output type is determined by evaluating the first element of the
>   input, unless it is specified

Your first input element produces output of type `int64`:

```
In [2]: data = np.array([-4.    , -3.57894737, -3.15789474, -2.73684211, -2.31578947,
   ...:    -1.89473684, -1.47368421, -1.05263158, -0.63157895, -0.21052632,
   ...:     0.21052632,  0.63157895,  1.05263158,  1.47368421,  1.89473684,
   ...:     2.31578947,  2.73684211,  3.15789474,  3.57894737,  4.        ])

In [3]: saw = lambda x: 0 if x < -2 or x > 2 else x

In [4]: saw_v = np.vectorize(saw)

In [5]: type(saw_v(data)[0])
Out[5]: numpy.int64

In [6]: type(saw_v(data[5:])[0])
Out[6]: numpy.float64
```

You have to specify `otype` while vectorizing your function:

```
In [9]: saw_v_f = np.vectorize(saw, otypes=[np.float])

In [10]: type(saw_v_f(data)[0])
Out[10]: numpy.float64

In [11]: saw_v_f(data)
Out[11]: 
array([ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
       -1.89473684, -1.47368421, -1.05263158, -0.63157895, -0.21052632,
        0.21052632,  0.63157895,  1.05263158,  1.47368421,  1.89473684,
        0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ])
```

Comment: Would just changing to `saw = lambda x: 0.0 if x < -2 or x > 2 else x` have worked?

Answer (score -1):

Seems to work for me with map.

```
map(saw, x)

[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1.89473684, -1.47368421, -1.0526315799999999, -0.63157894999999997, -0.21052631999999999, 0.21052631999999999, 0.63157894999999997, 1.0526315799999999, 1.47368421, 1.89473684, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: ...but the OP is using numpy.  This isn't relevant.

Comment: `np.array(list(map(saw,x)))` is just as fast as `vectorize` with this sample array.  So is `np.array([saw(i) for i in x])`